# What to try if React Native Expo is displaying blank for Web view

Tags: react-native, expo

I've been learning React Native Expo and had a simple app that ran well on Android and IO but the Web view was blank.

I compared it to the default "Awesome Project" example and dissected it step by step to find out what was causing the blank page. The solution might seem simple but it is not well documented so hopefully this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

1. Run  `npm install react-native-webview` from within your app folder
2. Add the following to the **dependencies** section of your package.json:

`"react-native-web": "^0.19.1",`

`"react-native-webview": "^11.26.1"`

(You can find out the latest version number to use here by visiting
[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview)

3. You should find the app now works on web as well as mobile.

If that doesn't work you can also try adding the following to the **devDependencies** section of package.json. These were the only other difference left between the working example and my initially non-working app when I did my step by step dissection.

```
"@svgr/webpack": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.19.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.76.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.1"
```

Leave a comment below if this helps you as would be useful for others to know.